# Fortran reshape - N-dimensional transpose

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, reshape, transpose, memory-layout

I'm trying to write some code in Fortran which requires the re-ordering of an n-dimensional array. I thought the [reshape](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/reshape) intrinsic combined with the `order` argument should allow this, however I'm running into difficulties.

Consider the following minimal example

```
program test
    implicit none
    real, dimension(:,:,:,:,:), allocatable :: matA, matB
    integer, parameter :: n1=3, n2=5, n3=7, n4=11, n5=13
    integer :: i1, i2, i3, i4, i5

    allocate(matA(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)) !Source array
    allocate(matB(n3,n2,n4,n1,n5)) !Reshaped array

    !Populate matA
    do i5=1, n5
       do i4=1, n4
          do i3=1, n3
             do i2=1, n2
                do i1=1, n1
                   matA(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5) = i1+i2*10+i3*100+i4*10000+i5*1000000
                enddo
             enddo
          enddo
       enddo
    enddo

    print*,"Ad1 : ",matA(:,1,1,1,1),shape(matA)
    matB = reshape(matA, shape(matB), order = [3,2,4,1,5])
    print*,"Bd4 : ",matB(1,1,1,:,1),shape(matB) !Leading dimension of A is the fourth dimension of B
end program test
```

I would expect this to result in

```
Ad1 : 1010111.00       1010112.00       1010113.00               3           5           7          11          13

Bd4 : 1010111.00       1010112.00       1010113.00               7           5          11           3          13
```

But instead I find:

```
Ad1 : 1010111.00       1010112.00       1010113.00               3           5           7          11          13

Bd4 : 1010111.00       1010442.00       1020123.00               7           5          11           3          13
```

I've tried this with `gfortran` (4.8.3 and 4.9) and `ifort` (11.0) and find the same results, so it's likely that I am simply misunderstanding something about how reshape works.

Can anybody shed any light on where I'm going wrong and how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `order=` is specified in `reshape` the elements of the result taken with permuted subscript order correspond to the elements of the source array.  That probably isn't entirely clear.  The Fortran 2008 standard states this as (ignoring the part about `pad=`)

> The elements of the result, taken in permuted subscript order ORDER (1), ..., ORDER (n), are those of SOURCE in normal array element order ..

What this means is that from your example with `order=[3,2,4,1,5]` there is the mapping to

```
matA(1,1,1,1,1), matA(2,1,1,1,1), matA(3,1,1,1,1), matA(1,2,1,1,1), ...
```

of

```
matB(1,1,1,1,1), matB(1,1,2,1,1), matB(1,1,3,1,1), matB(1,1,4,1,1), ...
```

with offset changing most rapidly in the third index of `matB` corresponding to most rapidly varying in the first of `matA`.  The next fastest varying in `matB` being dimension 2, then 4, and so on.

So, it's the elements `matB(1,1,1:3,1,1)` that correspond the `matA(:,1,1,1,1)`.

I've been explicit in the extent of that `matB` slice because you've a problem with the shape of `matB`: you want the shape of `matB` to be the inverse of the permutation given by the `order=` specifier.

You could write your example as

```
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: n1=3, n2=5, n3=7, n4=11, n5=13
  integer matA(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)
  integer matB(n4,n2,n1,n3,n5)  ! Inverse of permutation (3 2 4 1 5)
  integer i1, i2, i3, i4, i5

  forall (i1=1:n1, i2=1:n2, i3=1:n3, i4=1:n4, i5=1:n5) &
          matA(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5)=i1+i2*10+i3*100+i4*10000+i5*1000000

  print*,"Ad1 : ",matA(:,1,1,1,1),shape(matA)
  matB = reshape(matA, shape(matB), order = [3,2,4,1,5])
  print*,"Bd3 : ",matB(1,1,:,1,1),shape(matB)

end
```

Alternatively, if it's the shape of `matB` that you want, then it's the order permutation that wants inverting:

```
  matB = reshape(matA, shape(matB), order = [4,2,1,3,5])
```

---

At first glance, it may be natural to view the order relating to the dimensions of the source.  However, the following may clarify: the result of the reshaping is the same regardless of the shape of source (what is used are the elements of the array in natural order); the `order=` value has size equal to that of the `shape=` value. For the first of these, if the source were, say `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` (recall how we construct rank-2 arrays), then `order=` could never have any effect (it would have to be `[1]`) if it were used on the source.

Comment: Many thanks for this, it has clarified the working of `order`. I had read the specification but I think it was a case of reading what I expected to see rather than what it actually said. It means if we have`N=reshape(M,shape(N),order=[a,b,c])` then the first dimension of `M` becomes the _ath_ dimension of `N` etc.

Comment: It is natural to expect that the order is of the dimensions of the source.  However, perhaps the following may help change that intuition (or remind): the result of the reshaping is the same regardless of the shape of source (what is used are the elements of the array in natural order); the `order=` value has size equal to that of the `shape=` value.  For the first of these, if source were, say `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` (recall construction of 2-D arrays), then `order=` could never have any effect (it would have to be `[1]`) if it were used on the source.

Comment: That does indeed help my understanding, thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

Because I also feel the behavior of `order` for multi-dimensional arrays is quite non-intuitive, I made some code comparison below to make the situation even clear (in addition to the already complete @francescalus' answer). First, in a simple case, `reshape()` with and without `order` gives the following:

```
mat = reshape( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [2,4] )

=> [ 1  3  5  7  ;
     2  4  6  8  ]

mat = reshape( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [2,4], order=[2,1] )

=> [ 1  2  3  4  ;
     5  6  7  8  ]
```

This example shows that without `order` the elements are filled in the usual column-major way, while with `order=[2,1]` the 2nd dimension runs faster and so the elements are filled row-wise. The key point here is that the `order` specifies which dimension of the LHS (rather than the source array) runs faster (as emphasized in the above answer).

Now we apply the same mechanism to higher-dimensional cases. First, `reshape()` of the 5-dimensional array without `order`

```
matB = reshape( matA, [n3,n2,n4,n1,n5] )
```

corresponds to the explicit loops

```
k = 0
do i5 = 1, n5   !! (5)-th dimension of LHS
do i1 = 1, n1   !! (4)
do i4 = 1, n4   !! (3)
do i2 = 1, n2   !! (2)
do i3 = 1, n3   !! (1)-st dimension of LHS
    k = k + 1
    matB( i3, i2, i4, i1, i5 ) = matA_seq( k )
enddo;enddo;enddo;enddo;enddo
```

where `matA_seq` is a sequential view of `matA`

```
real, pointer :: matA_seq(:)
matA_seq( 1 : n1*n2*n3*n4*n5 ) => matA(:,:,:,:,:)
```

Now attaching `order=[3,2,4,1,5]` to `reshape()`,

```
matB = reshape( matA, [n3,n2,n4,n1,n5], order = [3,2,4,1,5] )
```

then the order of DO-loops is changed such that

```
k = 0
do i5 = 1, n5   !! (5)-th dim of LHS
do i3 = 1, n3   !! (1)
do i1 = 1, n1   !! (4)
do i2 = 1, n2   !! (2)
do i4 = 1, n4   !! (3)-rd dim of LHS
    k = k + 1
    matB( i3, i2, i4, i1, i5 ) = matA_seq( k )
enddo;enddo;enddo;enddo;enddo
```

This means that the 3rd dimension of `matB` (and thus `i4`) runs fastest (which corresponds to the second line in the above Answer). But what is desired by OP is

```
k = 0
do i5 = 1, n5   !! (5)-th dim of LHS
do i4 = 1, n4   !! (3)
do i3 = 1, n3   !! (1)
do i2 = 1, n2   !! (2)
do i1 = 1, n1   !! (4)-th dim of LHS
    k = k + 1
    matB( i3, i2, i4, i1, i5 ) = matA_seq( k )
enddo;enddo;enddo;enddo;enddo
```

which corresponds to

```
matB = reshape( matA, [n3,n2,n4,n1,n5], order = [4,2,1,3,5] )
```

i.e., the final line of the francescalus' answer.

Hope this comparison further clarifies the situation...

Comment: Thanks  I agree it is not very intuitive, although I do find your use of the "flattened" view of `matA` does help clarify the use of `order` further.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation is very useful. at the end, in the order option, we pick the place of the target array according to the original sequence.