# Fortran restructure data file

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a data file with 4 columns:

```
x    y    u    v
```

such that x and y are the coordinate positions associated to the values u and v.

The data is structured such that

```
x    y    u    v
1    1    #    #
2    1    #    #
3    1    #    #
...
```

However, I would like to restructure the file such that

```
x    y    u    v
1    1    #    #
1    2    #    #
1    3    #    #

...
```

Is there a function in fortran which can achieve this?

Comment: You are possibly thinking about the [`reshape`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37442346) function.

Comment: are the x,y values on a known dimension regular grid? If no what you need to do is read it all into a `4,n` array and sort.  Fortran has no intrinsic sort function, but not hard to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I never make claims about "pretty," but it should do the job.  Obviously, you will need to check your FORMAT statements:

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      REAL*8 :: U(4,4)
      REAL*8 :: V(4,4)
      INTEGER :: X, Y

      DO
         READ(*,'(2I2)',ADVANCE='NO',END=10) X,Y
         READ(*,'(2F6.1)',ADVANCE='YES',END=10) U(X,Y),V(X,Y)
      END DO

 10   CONTINUE
      WRITE(*,'(2I4,2F10.2)') ((I,J,U(I,J),V(I,J),J=1,4),I=1,4)

      END
```

I'm assuming that your arrays are already allocated properly.

Here's my input file:

```
$ cat test.in
 1 1    5.0  10.0
 2 1    1.3  -0.2
 3 1    5.1   0.0
 4 1   -9.1   3.0
 1 2    4.0   2.0
 2 2   14.0  -8.0
 3 2   -8.0   8.0
 4 2    4.0   9.6
 1 3    2.0   1.1
 2 3    3.4   8.0
 3 3    4.0   7.0
 4 3    4.0   4.1
 1 4    5.5   8.4
 2 4   34.1  23.0
 3 4   -4.1   4.0
 4 4    6.0   8.4
```

And the output:

```
$ cat test.in | ./a.out
 1 1    5.0  10.0
 1 2    4.0   2.0
 1 3    2.0   1.1
 1 4    5.5   8.4
 2 1    1.3  -0.2
 2 2   14.0  -8.0
 2 3    3.4   8.0
 2 4   34.1  23.0
 3 1    5.1   0.0
 3 2   -8.0   8.0
 3 3    4.0   7.0
 3 4   -4.1   4.0
 4 1   -9.1   3.0
 4 2    4.0   9.6
 4 3    4.0   4.1
 4 4    6.0   8.4
```

Comment: you actually can do that read at one shot: `read(unit,*)x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y)`  Obviously this assumes the `x,y` values in the file are integers.

Comment: I tried that at first, but I think I had my read format wrong.

Comment: no need to use a format, just list directed `*` works fine.