# Is there any Fortran function to transpose 3D array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

I need to transpose a 3D matrix in Fortran. I have a 3d array: `V(111,222,333)`; I need to transpose it to `V(333,111,222)`. Is there any function to do that in Fortran?

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to disagree with @IanBush and perhaps what follows is neither easy nor clear.  The following statement will return *a* permutation of the array `V`.  If I have got it right then the element at `V(i,j,k)` is sent to `V_prime(k,i,j)`.

```
V_prime = RESHAPE(source=V, shape=[size(V,3),size(V,1),size(V,2)], order=[2,3,1])
```

Whether this creates the permutation OP asks for is a bit unclear, I'm not aware that there is a single definition of the transpose of an array of rank other than 2. Changing the `order` will produce different permutations.

This question is probably a duplicate of [Fortran reshape - N-dimensional transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442346/fortran-reshape-n-dimensional-transpose). It is certainly worth reading the answers to that question which explain the use of `reshape` with `order` very well.

Comment: Yes, that's the point - I don't consider that easy or clear, while I think some nested loops are. But beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I had my brain addled at an early age by exposure to APL 

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks a lot. I will check this soon and post the results. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

There is no routine that will do this simply. I would write some loops, that is often the easiest and clearest way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the problem is: I have several variables like that (3D array of 800*400*500 size) which needs to be transposed. I am also trying to avoid writing parallel code. So I was looking for a function. What do you think about the "reshape" function with "order"?

Comment: Write your own function or subroutine to do it then, that's what I would do. Note 800*400*500 is over 1GByte, assuming double precision, so if you have "several" of them you may not be able to avoid writing parallel code anyway - but anyway, all code should be written with parallelism in mind nowadays.